# Add new keyword in postgresql 9

Tags: c++, postgresql, keyword

I want to add new keyword MAKE in postgresql. I added this statement in kwlist.h
PG_KEYWORD("make", MAKE, RESERVED_KEYWORD)

and also defined it in gram.y file at 2-3 places. But it is showing this error-

```
../../src/include/parser/kwlist.h:242:20: error: ‘MAKE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 PG_KEYWORD("make", MAKE, RESERVED_KEYWORD)
                    ^
keywords.c:26:30: note: in definition of macro ‘PG_KEYWORD’
 #define PG_KEYWORD(a,b,c) {a,b,c},
```

Can anyone help me in this???